# Xamarin Resource.Designer.cs generating const instead of static

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, generated-code

I have on .NET 6 project using xamarin.android where the resource designer file generated with an error `CS0131 : The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`:

```cs
public static void UpdateIdValues()
{
    global::MyGame.Resource.Color.alignment_marker_color = global::MyGame.Resource.Color.alignment_marker_color;
    global::MyGame.Resource.Color.white_transparent = global::MyGame.Resource.Color.white_transparent;
    global::MyGame.Resource.Dimension.alignment_marker_height = global::MyGame.Resource.Dimension.alignment_marker_height;
    // ...
}
```

with values generated like so :

```cs
public partial class Color
{
            
    // aapt resource value: 0x7F010000
    public const int alignment_marker_color = 2130771968;

    // aapt resource value: 0x7F010001
    public const int white_transparent = 2130771969;
    // ...

}
```

Is it an issue with the xamarin dependency ? If so, is it something i can solve through nuget ? dotnet workload ?

Comment: Maybe delete .obj folder, reopen project, try again?

Comment: This is normal behavior. In your Application project resources will be const, while in Android Class Libraries values will be static. If you have issues with the generated code in Resource.Designer.cs, try remove the file and rebuild

Comment: @Cheesebaron I understand for the const, although re-generating the file keeps the error. Should `UpdateIdValues` be able to update const values?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue myself, and after much trial and error, I found that the issue was caused by me having two assemblies, both containing Resources which had the same "Default Namespace" in their project properties.

After changing the namespace in one of them, deleting the bin and obj folders, running a Clean (overkill) I was able to successfully rebuild the project without error.

Comment: What do you mean by "two assemblies"?

Comment: Now I see - you mean two projects in the solution. And each project had a default namespace set to the same value. Changing them did help.

Comment: Hi yes. Two projects with the same Default Namespace. Glad you sorted it out.